# TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, compiler-errors, react-redux

this is the place where my code is getting stuck at onClick();

i wanted to change the title of the chat name using dispatch (i am following a youtube channel -clever programmer for a imessage clone) but the action doesn't get dispatched but the error is popping up,
i am using firebase as backend.

```
import React from 'react'
import "./SidebarChat.css"
import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import setChat from "./features/chatSlice"

function SidebarChat({id,chatName}) {

const dispatch =  useDispatch();

    return (
        <div 
        onClick={()=>(
            dispatch(setChat({
                    chatId: id,
                    chatName: chatName
                })))
        }
        className='sidebarChat'>
            <Avatar />
            <div className="sidebarChat__info">
                <h3>{chatName}</h3>
                <p>Last messg</p>
                <small>timestamp</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SidebarChat
```

this is the chatslice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const chatSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'chat',
  initialState: {
    chatId: null,
    chatName: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    setChat: (state,action) =>  {
      state.chatId = action.payload.chatId;
      state.chatName = action.payload.chatName;
    },
  },
});

export const { setChat } = chatSlice.actions;


export const selectChatId = (state) => state.chat.chatId;
export const selectChatName = (state) => state.chat.chatName;

export default chatSlice.reducer;
```

this is the redux store

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from '../features/userSlice';
import chatReducer from '../features/chatSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
    chat: chatReducer,
  },
});
```

I am a begginner and i have gone each and every page available but i couldnt get anything can anyone please help me

This is the error message its throwing
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import `setChat` like this.

```js
import { setChat } from "./features/chatSlice"
```

Comment: you are my life saver i was going to drop this project but thanks again

Comment: If this worked out for you, feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow so I don't know what accept means anyways I tried to like your answer which stack is not allowing me as my reputation is less than 15